# I get blank screen when execute http://localhost:9001/forms/frmservlet

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, oracleforms

I get blank screen when execute http://localhost:9001/forms/frmservlet.
I am using java 1.8.0_321, WebLogic 12 y forms 12.
I have lost several days trying to fix.
Any recomendation?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre] along with any error messages or stack traces that running your code produces. As it is, your question lacks sufficient information for us to answer it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

A blank page is a 'successful' response from the code running behind /forms/frmservlet.

There are a few things you can check:

- Which code is sending the blank page? Is it your code or is your webapp on a different path? Is your servlet mapped correctly?
- Look at the HTML source in the browser to understand better the blank page
- Check Weblogic's logfiles to see if something unusal is in there

All this may sound pretty generic but you did not give more details either.